# Erro de passagem de parâmetro de matriz

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, matriz, parâmetros

Estou tentando entender o funcionamento de ponteiros para uma matriz. Para isso, elaborei o pequeno programa abaixo. Cometi algum equívoco, pois, na linha indicada, está ocorrendo erro (*segmentation fault*).

Qual o modo correto de passar o ponteiro que aponta para uma matriz, de modo como tentei no exemplo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float t1[4][2];
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        t1[i%4][i%2]=i+1;
    }
    teste1(t1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
void teste1(float ** t1)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t",t1[i%4][i%2]);   // Erro nesta linha ("segmentation fault")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O problema está na declaração do parâmetro na função `teste1`. Se você está passando um *array* de duas dimensões (4X2) do tipo `float`, então a função deve receber o mesmo tipo no parâmetro.

Na verdade o código nem compilava (em bom compilador). Além de não reconhecer a função `teste1` havia incompatibilidade de tipos no parâmetro. Provavelmente você está usando um compilador que não atende os padrões da linguagem, por isso conseguiu compilar. Ou o código real que você compilou é diferente do postado.

Eu inverti as duas funções para que a `teste1` seja declarada/definida antes de ser usada. Também poderia só declarar antes e definir depois mas acho que o código fica mais sujo assim.

Também arrumei o cálculo de do segundo índice que estava errado conforme indicado nos comentários:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void teste1(float t1[4][1]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf("%f\t", t1[i % 4 ][i / 4]);
}
int main() {
    float t1[4][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) t1[i % 4][i / 4] = i + 1;
    teste1(t1);
    getchar();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kUIXdg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/szbzsihy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/PassArray.c).

No comentário foi falado em deixar genérico. Isto é possível com *arrays* se usar um compilador que atenda ao padrão C99 (o GCC permite até que os tamanhos das dimensões possam ser passados após o *array*). O cabeçalho da função teria que ficar assim:

```
void teste1(int m, int n, float t1[m][n]) {
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w1gfAT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/khemmgpc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/PassArray2.c).

Mas se realmente quiser usar um ponteiro como parâmetro e quiser generalizar tem que fazer isto:

Neste caso a `teste1` está recebendo como ponteiro (e não ponteiro para ponteiro).

O cálculo da posição do elemento está sendo feito manualmente já que está sendo tratado com ponteiro e não *array*.

A chamada também precisa fazer um *casting* para adequar o tipo de *array* para ponteiro.

E também há parâmetros para receber o total de linhas e colunas da matriz.

Também usei `#define` para evitar se perder quando altera o tamanho da matriz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define linhas 4
#define colunas 2

void teste1(float * t1, int totalLinhas, int totalColunas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLinhas* totalColunas; i++) printf("%f\t", *((t1 + (i % totalLinhas) * totalColunas) + (i / totalLinhas)));
}
int main() {
    float t1[linhas][colunas];
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas * colunas; i++) t1[i % linhas][i / linhas] = i + 1;
    teste1((float *)t1, linhas, colunas);
    getchar();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KJq3lo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hcpdjcar-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/PassArray3.c).

Comment: Grato!
Usei essa forma (sem indicação das dimensões) pois estava pensando em utilização com dimensões variadas. 
A solução que buscava é a segunda.
O código foi transcrito exatamente como compilei. Estou usando o CodeBlocks (versão 13.12 - Windows unicode - 32bits).
Não consegui aumentar a pontuação desta resposta, pois ainda estou com pontuação insuficiente para votar.

Comment: Este código não funciona para dimensões variadas, vou colocar outro que funciona. O CodeBlocks não é um compilador é um IDE. Tem que ver qual o compilador ele está usando. Pode ser parâmetros de compilação. Eu só compilo com o máximo de segurança ligado, assim o compilador não permite fazer coisas que funcionam em uma situação e e outra não. Veja o [tour], você pode aceitar a resposta mais certa para sua pergunta sempre (não precisa fazer já) e acho que você já tem reputação para votar agora.

Comment: Uma coisa que não entendi, após ver o código funcionando, é que esperava que fosse escrito 1,2,...8 no stdout e não 5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8.
O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Veja http://ideone.com/I4m9EU O problema está nesta conta do resto, ela não está resultando no que você espera. A resposta está de acordo com o que você fez, veja esse código aqui no comentário se é o que você deseja.

Comment: Era somente um teste. Mas estava pensando nisso mesmo. Antes de ver esta sua última postagem, havia feito assim:

http://ideone.com/c4XFWD

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Adicionei um código que o compilador aceita bem, mas fornece uns resultados esquisitos, com matriz de tipo int (troca linha por colunas aparentemente). Se mudar para float, também compila, mas fornece resultados zerados.

Comment: Em compilador decente este código não compila. Eu não trabalho com compiladores ruins: http://ideone.com/defIl7. Se você insistir nele você vai aprender errado e vai sofrer mais pra frente. De qualquer forma este é outro código, outro problema, portanto deve ser outra pergunta. Informe seu compilador nela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19487/discussion-between-roberto-santos-and-bigown).

Comment: Não estou com muito tempo hoje. Faça o que te te falei, faça outra pergunta e eu tentarei responder, ou outra pessoa poderá responder.

Comment: Neste link, encontra-se um pequeno programa para multiplicação de duas matrizes, a partir das orientações que o Bigown passou, e outros experimentos que tentei: Utilizei duas rotinas para a multiplicação: uma utilizando aritmética de ponteiros e outra índices: http://ideone.com/7DnFwe