# Passar matriz para funçoes em C

Tags: c, c++, matriz

Boa noite, seguinte estou com um problema na hora de passar uma matriz para uma função em C.
Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
void funcao(int mat[][num]);
int main() {
    scanf(%d,&num);
}
```

É basicamente o seguinte, eu defino o tamanho da matriz na função main, então a declaraçao da função acima do código aponta que num não é uma constante então dá erro, queria saber como posso essa matriz pra uma função. Vlw

Comment: Acho que é duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87638/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43948/101.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você use alocação dinâmica:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funcao(int **mat, int num);
int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int **mat=(int**)malloc(num*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        mat[i]=(int*)malloc(num*sizeof(int));
    funcao(mat, num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta meter assim:

```
void funcao(int **mat, int dim_linha, int dim_coluna);
```

Em que `mat` é um vetor multidimensional, e passas a dimensão da matriz